# C++ converting variable integer to string

Tags: c++

The problem I am encountering is the warning message I get when running the c++ .cpp code. Is there another way I can convert an integer to a string.

[image]

Here is a snapshot of the code I am running, and where the problem is:

```
string empId2 = to_string(empId);
```

Comment: Either your library doesn't support `to_string` (introduced with c++11), or you need to compile in c++11 standards mode or later (`-std=c++11` on gcc and clang).

Comment: Don't link images. Copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a header file. Check your `#include` directives. That one is gcc's standart warning for cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is shown when the function, in this case to_string is defined after it is used. Either move the definition of the function above or in a new file and include its header.

Comment: Why would he define `to_string` himself?

Comment: He doesn't have to, he can include <string>

Answer (score -1):

You can use std ostringstream to convert from any type to string
e.g:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss<<empId;
string empIdStr = oss.str();
```

Comment: Not "any type", and you missed the point of using `to_string`.